# Stability theorem in numerical eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

This [paper](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/linear_algebra/chpt6.pdf) mentions the stability theorem in $ 6.1 $ as following: If $ A_{n \times n} $ and $ E_{n \times n} $ are real and symmetric matrix and $ \hat{A} = A + E. $ Let $ \lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \dots, \lambda_{n} $ and $ \hat{\lambda_{1}}, \hat{\lambda_{2}}, \dots, \hat{\lambda_{n}} $ be eigenvalues of $ A $ and $ \hat{A}, $ respectively. Then 
$$ \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (\lambda_{i} - \hat{\lambda_{i}})^2 \le ||E||_{F}^2 $$
where $ ||E||_{F} $ is the Frobenius norm of $ E. $

My question is, can we prove the theorem in the case where $ A $ is $ \it{not} $ symmetric?

Comment: My friend,  turn pages of the paper until page 5.